# Not understanding how the process.argv is being used in this Node.js function

Tags: node.js

I am working through exercise 5 of the "learnyounode" module.

This is the function and solution:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function (err, list) {
    if(err){throw err}
  list.forEach(function (file) {
    if (path.extname(file) === '.' + process.argv[3])
      console.log(file)
  });
});
```

Now I didn't get the solution myself because I was having a hard time wrapping my head around this request:

> Create a program that prints a list of files in a given directory,
>   filtered by the extension of the files. You will be provided a
>   directory name as the first argument to your program     (e.g.
>   '/path/to/dir/') and a file extension to filter by as the second
>   argument.
>
> For example, if you get 'txt' as the second argument then you will need to filter the list to only files that end with .txt.
>   Note that the second argument will not come prefixed with a '.'.
>
> Keep in mind that the first arguments of your program are not the     first values of the process.argv array, as the first two
>   values are reserved for system info by Node.

Does this mean **if** the program was really being accessed like you would in the terminal/command prompt what `process.argv` would be receiving would be the following?

```
0: /usr/local/bin/node
1: /Users/me/work/node/filter-list.js
2: '/path/to/dir/'
3: txt
```

Comment: you can just run the code and see

Comment: @Sikorski Thanks!

Comment: Yes. In your problem, process.argv would be receiving the above values as you mentioned. The first element will be process.execPath .The second element will be the path to the JavaScript file being executed. The remaining elements will be any additional command line arguments. Run the example mentioned here  https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv  to know the exact values.